# Ionic $http (match id from one Rest response to another)

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic mobile app which returns REST response. I created REST web service in Spring. In my All Jobs (TAB) view, I have `(ion-list)` filled with some REST response. 
Example: [Image: All Jobs List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LJwD.png)

Example:

This is rest response which is called in jobs tab (getAllJobsRest):

> getAllJobsRest

```
  {
    "id": 232,
    "jobId": 119,
    "jobName": "iProducts",
    "jobLevel": 3,
    "jobLevelName": "ERROR",
    "jobMessage": "message",
    "jobEventCtime": 1493972832273,
    "jobErrorStatus": 1,
    "jobComment": null,
    "jobSolvedBy": null,
    "jobEventMtime": null
    },
    {
    "id": 13477371,
    "jobId": 15,
    "jobName": "eGoogle",
    "jobLevel": 1,
    "jobLevelName": "INFO",
    "jobMessage": "End job",
    "jobEventCtime": 1458925361763,
    "jobErrorStatus": 1,
    "jobComment": "processed",
    "jobSolvedBy": "ttester",
    "jobEventMtime": null
    },
```

> getJobHistoryREST

```
{
"id": 13714685,
"jobId": 119,
"jobName": "iProducts",
"jobLevel": 1,
"jobLevelName": "INFO",
"jobMessage": null,
"jobEventCtime": 1483149631910,
"jobErrorStatus": 4,
"jobComment": null,
"jobSolvedBy": null,
"jobEventMtime": 1483149631910
},
{
"id": 13714684,
"jobId": 119,
"jobName": "iProducts",
"jobLevel": 1,
"jobLevelName": "INFO",
"jobMessage": null,
"jobEventCtime": 1483149631197,
"jobErrorStatus": 4,
"jobComment": null,
"jobSolvedBy": null,
"jobEventMtime": 1483149631197
}
```

Everything works for now... The problem is when I click on some item in ion-list I want to show again ion-list filled with *getJobHistoryREST* but only with job that match **jobId** from *getAllJobsRest* **jobId**. 
I don't know how to match **jobId** from first Rest response with second Rest response.
I've tried with some functions in 'JobDetailCtrl' ->

```
TCCService.getJobById($scope.jobId).success(function (response) {
      $scope.jobIdList = response;
    })});
```

but returns empty Object.
I'll put my code here so I hope that anyone who is willing to help will give me a right answer. Thanks.

> This is my app.js file:

```
    var app = angular.module('tcc', [
  'ionic',
  'tcc.controllers',
  'tcc.service',
  'tcc.directive',
  'restangular'
]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('tab.jobs', {
    url: '/jobs',
    views: {
      'tab-jobs': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-jobs.html',
        controller: 'JobCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  $stateProvider.state('tab.job-detail', {
    url: '/jobs/:jobId',
    views: {
      'tab-jobs': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/detail/job.html',
        controller: 'JobDetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
```

> tccservice.js

```
angular.module('tcc.service', [])

  .factory('TCCService', function($http) {


    var jobs ="https://ce35285c.ngrok.io/tcc/v1/jobStatus/getLastJobStatusForAllJobs";    
    var jobStatusHistory = "https://ce35285c.ngrok.io/tcc/v1/jobStatus/getJobStatusHistory";
    var components=[];

  return {

    getComponents: function() {
      return $http.get(url);
    },

    getJobs: function() {
      return $http.get(jobs);
    },

    getJobById: function(jobId) {
      return $http.get(jobStatusHistory, {params: {
        componentId: jobId
      }});
    }
```

> controllers.js

```
  //Job Controller
  app.controller('JobCtrl', function($scope, TCCService) {

    //  v1/jobStatus/getLastJobStatusForAllJobs
    TCCService.getJobs().success(function (response) {
      $scope.jobs = response;
      $scope.jobId = response.jobId;
    });

    $scope.remove = function(jobId) {
      TCCService.removeJob(jobId);
    }
  });
 // Job Details Controller
 app.controller('JobDetailCtrl', function($scope, TCCService) {
    var job = $scope.jobId;

    TCCService.getJobs().success(function (response) {
      $scope.jobs = response;
    });

    TCCService.getJobById(job).success(function (response) {
      $scope.jobIdList = response;
    })});
```